# Trigonometric Sums - URSS

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math

Calculate the value of the sums:

(a) $\cos x+\binom{n}{1}\cos 2x +\cdots+\binom{n}{n} \cos (n+1)x $;

(b) $\sin x+\binom{n}{1}\sin 2x +\cdots+\binom{n}{n} \sin (n+1)x $.

Comment: @Amzoti I'm sure the URSS is long gone!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: thank you, just trying to be safe given very recent history with postings from ongoing contests - thx!

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Consider the real and imaginary parts of the binomial expansion of $e^{ix}(1+e^{ix})^n$

Then write $$1+e^{ix} = 2e^{ix/2}\cos\frac{x}{2}$$

Comment: yes, I got there! and now?

Comment: Write $1+e^{ix} = 2e^{ix/2} \cos(x/2)$